# How to correctly use "self" resource in Magento 2 webapi.xml

Tags: magento2, webapi, oauth

I have created some endpoints in a module that have a resource of "self"

When I call the request using a jQuery ($.post) I get an **Not allowed to accesses resource "self"**. These requests are done on the onpage.phtml template.

According to the Magento 2 documentation "*if a customer is logged in to the Magento storefront and the JavaScript widget invokes the self API, details for the logged-in customer are fetched*". To note the customer IS logged in.

Note: I am not sending customer token. Do you need this? You can then make this request from anywhere if you do use a token. Which breaks the statement that only AJAX calls can get a "self" resource.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?